# Local Storage doesn't save data

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am using ionic 4 to build a weather app with the `openweathermap` api. l want to use the [local storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) api to save the users city, the data is saved when you reload the page, the problem is when I reload the app, the data is not stored.

Weather provider

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weatherprovider',
  templateUrl: './weatherprovider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weatherprovider.component.scss'],
})
export class WeatherproviderComponent implements OnInit {
  public appId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  public baseUrl='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
  constructor(public https: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  city(city:string){
    let url=this.baseUrl
    url +='?q='+city
    url+='&appId='+this.appId

    return this.https.get(url);
  }

}
```

`home.ts` to get data from weather provider and load local storage

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AddPagePage } from '../add-page/add-page.page';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WeatherproviderComponent } from '../weatherprovider/weatherprovider.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

 public weatherList = []
  check = ''
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController,public weather : WeatherproviderComponent,
    private storage: Storage){

  }


  // Window Modal for add weather citiis
  async addWeather(){

    const AddWeatherModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AddPagePage,

    });

    await AddWeatherModal.present();
    await  AddWeatherModal.onDidDismiss().then((r) => {
        if(r){

          this.getWeather(r.data.result)
          console.log(r.data.result)
        }

    });
  }

  // get weather opeartion form main weather provider
    getWeather(city :string){

    this.weather.city(city).subscribe(data=>{

      this.weatherList.push(data)             
                                 ///  HERE blowe  l use local storage to save city 

       this.storage.set(city, JSON.stringify(city));

      this.storage.get(city).then((val) => {


      console.log('Your city is', val);
        });


    })

   }

}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why not use local storage directly, rather than `@ionic/storage`

Comment: l didn't found it  !!

Comment: Duplicated with [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232455/using-localstorage-ionic-2). you can refer to it to resolve you problem.

Comment: @NhutLe , l am sorry ,  Did not help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try using local storage directly like this

update `import { Component } from '@angular/core';` to `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

and

update `export class HomePage {` to `export class HomePage implements OnInit {`

```
ngOnInit() {
  let items_json = localStorage.getItem('cities');
  if(items_json) {
     let items = JSON.parse(items_json);
     items.map((item)=>{
        this.weatherList.push(item.data);
     });
  }
}

getWeather(city :string){
  this.weather.city(city).subscribe(data=>{

    this.weatherList.push(data) 

    //  save city with data
    this.saveWeatherEntry(city, data);

    // test the storage, 
    let entry = this.getWeatherEntry(city);
    console.log(city);
    console.log(entry);
  });
}

saveWeatherEntry(city, data) {
  // check if exist before in local storage
  let items_json = localStorage.getItem('cities');
  let items = [];
  if(items_json) {
     items = JSON.parse(items_json);
     let city_index = -1;
     for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].city == city) {
          city_index = i;
          break;
        }
     }

     if(city_index != -1) {
        items[city_index].data = data;
     } else {
        items.push({
           city: city,
           data: data
        });
     }

  } else {
     items.push({
        city: city,
        data: data
     });
  }   
  //save changes
  localStorage.setItem('cities', JSON.stringify(items));
}

getWeatherEntry(city) {
  // check if exist before in local storage
  let items_json = localStorage.getItem('cities');
  if(items_json) {
    let items = JSON.parse(items_json);
    let city_index = -1;
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       if(items[i].city == city) {
         return items[i].data;
       }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: it is same problem ! , when l reload page l got empty page , l have to select city again to show me data weather . but l notice your code is recoding data in local storage you can see here [https://i.imgur.com/Iu3bohH.png] but he doesn't  not showing when l reload page !

Comment: yes its meant to record in localStorage. That means its working. Let me update the answer, so you can see it after reload

Comment: Its been updated, I implemented `OnInit` to the class. Try it out

Comment: l don't know how to thank you , you really save me , thank you very much . he is working now

Comment: but dose he update data weather auto ? if he save it in local storage ? [https://i.imgur.com/RlSI7Px.png]

Comment: Glad it worked. But i dont understand your last question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189724/discussion-between-jonathan-k-and-ali-ghassan).